# Should I use a regression or classification framework to predict rankings?

Tags: machine-learning

My dependent variable is a performance ranking (relative to the other individuals). For example, one individual would be ranked first, another second, another third, etc. Would I use a classification or regression framework to model this?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a classification task. Since your $y$ is ordered, you may also consider "[ordered probit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_probit)" or "[ordered logit](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/)". These methods make sure that the order in $y$ is accounted for.